# Fortify Null Deference

Tags: c#, fortify

These two lines are getting flagged for Null Deference in our C# .net 4.8 code.

```
if (tm != null)  { 
                tms.Remove(tm);
                Session["TeamMembers"] = tms;
            }

ViewBag.DocketRcvdFromPolicy = PolicyMessages["xx"];
```

I tried doing this to fix the first

```
  tmss.Remove(tm == null ? null : tm);
```

then these:

```
 if (PolicyMessages["xx"] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(PolicyMessages["xx"]))
    {
        ViewBag.DocketRcvdFromPolicy = PolicyMessages["xx"];
    }
```

then tried this code:

```
ViewBag.DocketRcvdFromPolicy = (PolicyMessages["xx"] == null ? "null" : PolicyMessages["xxx"]);
```

two to fix the second. Nothing works both of these got flagged...any help would be apprecitaed
Thanks
JT

Comment: You have `["xxx"]` and `["xx"]` - is that a typo?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
if (PolicyMessages["xx"] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(PolicyMessages["xx"]))
{
    ViewBag.DocketRcvdFromPolicy = PolicyMessages["xx"];
}
```

OR

```
ViewBag.DocketRcvdFromPolicy = (PolicyMessages["xx"] == null ? null : PolicyMessages["xxx"]);
```

The problem with your code is that you are adding `ViewBag.DocketRcvdFromPolicy = (PolicyMessages["xx"] == null ? "null" : PolicyMessages["xxx"]);` this line after your if statement and that is unnecessary.

Comment: Sorry edited my issue. Those were two seperate tries. Both still got flagged so not sure what it's complaining about.

Comment: @user2883963you tms variable can also be null